# window-based app or view-based app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

when thinking of developing an app for iphone, I got confused of to choose between window or view based application. 
for example, I want to built an application such as an e-library system that supports: adding titles to a data store, updating titles, deleting titles and rate on them.
which one should I choose and why ?

another question: can a view controller be added to a window based app as well as the view based app?

thanks for your help.

EDIT: can anybody give a real world example on view and window based applications ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewBased App and tableView controls with it.Actually your will need to mix up different approach!But using window based app for iphone will not be a good idea i think.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such difference in both

In View Based app you will get a default view controller in window.

In Window Based app you will not get anything by default already added in window, you have to add your own view.

Answer (score 2):

hi friend 
actually it depends you not need to get confused . if your primary layout shows many tabs below so you can choose tabbar based , if you hav much with navigation then you choose navigation based , actually you have to choose when you start making your application.. For this application i suggest view based application

Answer (score 2):

window based app are the starting point of any app, it gives you the bare minimum to start whit. The rest of the app are actually just templates to help delopers learn or just to make the app quicker.